# How to connect SQL Server with Yii2

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

I got errors when trying to connecting SQL server with yii2.

SQL Server and PHP code are in separated server.

The PHP environment is PHP 7.0.31 on Ubuntu 18.04.

And Database Server Environment is MS SQL SERVER v9.00.1399.06 on Window NT 6.1

And I installed the PDO Drive as following

```
apt install php7.0-sybase
```

The following is my main-local.php

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\mssql\PDO',
        'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=xxxx',
        'username' => '<username>',
        'password' => '<password>',
        'charset' => 'utf8'
],
```

And i got the following error message.

```
Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Missing required parameter "dsn" when instantiating "yii\db\mssql\PDO".


1. in /var/www/html/ms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php at line 466

2. in /var/www/html/ms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php at line 370 – yii\di\Container::resolveDependencies([yii\di\Instance, yii\di\Instance, yii\di\Instance, yii\di\Instance], ReflectionClass)
```

Seems related to class reflction but I have no idea on how to solve it.

Hope someone can give a help hand on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
'db' => [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'driverName' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=xx.xx.xx.xx;Database=xxxx',
    'username' => '<username>',
    'password' => '<password>',
    'charset' => 'utf8'
],
```

Comment: It turns to  PDOException: could not find driver

Comment: But i got pdo_sqlsrv in phpinfo(). Is there any extra requiremt for the driver?

Comment: I'm not sure but I've seen several discussions online where people had problems with proper PDO drivers for MSSQL. Just in case you might want to check if you have got both console and web PHP configurations updated with this library.

Comment: @Bizley how to configure sqlsrv in console php

Comment: @SaranyaSubramanian just add the db config in the console configuration.

Answer (score 0):

below my solution for mssql connection:

from phpinfo() i know that 
PHP Extension Build API20190902,TS,VC15

then in file php.ini in folder ..\xampp\php
insert this

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll

I have downloaded this dll from microsoft site 
Put the dll in folder ..\xampp\php\ext

in your framework of yii2, in file ..\basic\config\db.php
this is the connection string

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=xxxxx\xxxxx;Database=xxxxx',
'username' => 'xxx',
'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

I hope that will be useful.
Regards
Alessio